# Compilar archivo .apk desde proyecto vacío de Unity (con IL2CPP) = 250 mb!

Tags: android, unity3d, apk

Tengo que cambiar la forma de generar archivos .apk en Unity para subirlos a Google Play (con motivos de los cambios de agosto 2019). Pero tengo graves problemas con el tamaño del/los .apk

Venia usando la versión 2017.3. Probé con 2018.4, pero debido a problemas cambié a 2017.4, y el resultado ha sido el mismo.

Anteriormente, el archivo apk generado (con 2017.3) tenía aproximadamente 35 mb. Ahora, usando IL2CPP para generar un apk para ARM64 y ARM32 no puedo obtener nada inferior a 450 mb!!!

He usado muchas combinaciones y no he logrado cambios significativos. En detalle:

Hice pruebas utilizando un **proyecto vacío** (solo una escena simple) y haciendo estas combinaciones:

```
Scripting runtime: **NET 3.5** <br>
Scripting backend: **IL2CPP** <br>
Api compatibility: **NET 2.0** <br>
Target architec: **ARMv7 y 64** <br>
file.apk = **23mb** <br>
file.0.1-v1.symbols.zip: **311mb**  

--------------------------------------
Scripting runtime: **NET 3.5** <br>
Scripting backend: **IL2CPP** <br>
Api compatibility: **NET 2.0 subset** <br>
Target architec: **ARMv7 y 64** <br>
file.apk = **14mb** <br>
file.0.1-v1.symbols.zip: **211mb** 
--------------------------------------

Scripting runtime: **NET 4.6** <br>
Scripting backend: **IL2CPP** <br>
Api compatibility: **NET 4.6** <br>
Target architec: **ARMv7 y 64** <br>
file.apk = **20mb** <br>
file.0.1-v1.symbols.zip: **464mb**  

--------------------------------------  

Scripting runtime: **NET 3.5** <br>
Scripting backend: **Mono** <br>
Api compatibility: **NET 2.0 subset** <br>
Target architec: **ARMv7** <br>
file.apk = **10mb** (1 solo archivo)
---------------------------------------

Scripting runtime: **NET 3.5** <br>
Scripting backend: **IL2CPP** <br>
Api compatibility: **NET 2.0 subset** <br>
Target architec: **ARM 64** <br>
file.apk = **8mb** <br>
file.0.1-v1.symbols.zip: **108mb**
```

Con IL2CPP nunca pude lograr un solo archivo .apk. Siempre genera 2. También utilicé "**strip engine code**", "**Split application binary**" y "**Build app Bundles**", pero no hubo cambios significativos.

Y lo peor, usando mi proyecto original, los valores más pequeños obtenidos fueron: file.apk (aprox. 25 mb) file.symbols.zip (aprox. 550 mb) !!!

Anteriormente (2017.3) con el mismo proyecto, obtuve un solo archivo .apk de 35 mb aprox. ¿Es posible mejorar esto? Estos valores son para asustar a los usuarios. Nadie querrá descargar e instalar la aplicación. He leído sobre las diferencias entre Mono e IL2CPP pero he encontrado muy poca información sobre este problema de tamaño. ¿Esto es normal ahora? El gran aumento en el tamaño de los archivos .apk e inamovible?

Gracias por adelantado.